# Add multiple markers on each coordinates in flask-googlemaps

Tags: python, google-maps, flask

I tried to do a simple car rental web project using flask, but meet an issue in add multiple markers on coordinates in flask-googlemaps, tried did this according to the tutorial https://github.com/rochacbruno/Flask-GoogleMaps ,

below is my code for add multiple coordinates on google map

```
catdatas = CarsDataset.query.all()
locations = [d.serializer() for d in catdatas]
carmap = Map(
    identifier="carmap",
    style="height:500px;width:500px;margin:0;",
    lat=locations[0]['lat'],
    lng=locations[0]['lng'],
    markers=[(loc['lat'], loc['lng']) for loc in locations]
)
```

each coordinates are successful added, but I don't know how to add multiple markers on it.. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of GoogleMapsFlask, you can put in the "markers" key a list of dictionaries (objects). Example:

```
[
          {
             'icon': 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
             'lat': 37.4419,
             'lng': -122.1419,
             'infobox': "<b>Hello World</b>"
          },
          {
             'icon': 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
             'lat': 37.4300,
             'lng': -122.1400,
             'infobox': "<b>Hello World from other place</b>"
          }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried use the dictionary format before, but seems to show only one markers on map..